# Difference between alt+tab and alt+escape

Tags: window, display-manager

On my GNOME + Ubuntu system, both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>+ switch between windows.

What exactly is the difference, if any, between them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between different programs on the same workspace (if activated) with a popup.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> switches between different programs without a popup.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (key below Esc) switches between different instances of a program.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between all programs regardless of the workspace (if activated) with a popup.

Comment: Nice overview of the shortcuts !

Comment: At least for me, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kdb>Esc</kbd> switches to the last window used, regardless of if it's another program or a different instance, but it only toggle between two different windows.

Comment: @redbmk Alt+Esc once takes you to the last window you had.  If you hold down the Alt key and tap the Esc again and again it will cycle through the windows.

Also, it looks like Alt+Esc respects workspaces, i.e. only cycles through the windows in the current workspace

Finally it looks like Alt-Esc works like Alt-Tab did in earlier versions, i.e. it cycles through the *windows*, not the apps.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>escape</kbd> is for the next window without the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> popup. So it's the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> but without the popup.

Comment: See my comments on @Fabby's answer, it appears (so far) that Alt-Esc has several other differences in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> looks like it's a custom keyboard shortcut that either you, some program or someone else put into place. If both pop-ups for the shortcuts look the same, they are the same.

Check System Settings>Keyboard>Custom Shortcuts to see if there are any set.

Comment: It's a [default keyboard in gnome3](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-list/2014-March/msg00020.html) which probably comes from [Windows 2.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.03.windowsconfidential.aspx)